# ng-repeat Return empty rows

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I tried with below code, but it is returning an empty row (more than 30+) of the table.

json

```
"[{\"COMPANY_ID\":\"1\",\"COMPANY_DESC\":\"11\",\"COMPANY_CURRENCY\":\"1\",\"ACTIVE\":true,\"IS_HEADOFFICE\":true,\"ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_ID\":\"1\"},{\"COMPANY_ID\":\"2\",\"COMPANY_DESC\":\"2\",\"COMPANY_CURRENCY\":\"22\",\"ACTIVE\":false,\"IS_HEADOFFICE\":false,\"ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_ID\":\"1\"}]"
```

Html

```
 <tr ng-repeat = "company in companies track by $index"">
   <td>{{ company.COMPANY_ID }}</td>
   <td>{{ company.COMPANY_DESC }}</td>
   <td>{{ company.COMPANY_CURRENCY }}</td>
 </tr>
```

App

```
<script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://localhost:52087/api/accountmapping")
                .success(function (response){
      $scope.companies = angular.fromJson(response); 
      console.log(angular.fromJson(response));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `then` instead of `success`. `success` is deprecated since angular version 1.4

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://localhost:52087/api/accountmapping")
                .then(function (response){
      $scope.companies = response.data; 
      console.log($scope.companies);
    });
  });
```

Comment: It is returning empty table again. :(

Answer (score 0):

I try to mirror your codes but i don't find that error, please **check** my codes and tell me what i miss to show that error for me.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
    
    var myJsonAsText = '[{\"COMPANY_ID\":\"1\",\"COMPANY_DESC\":\"11\",\"COMPANY_CURRENCY\":\"1\",\"ACTIVE\":true,\"IS_HEADOFFICE\":true,\"ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_ID\":\"1\"}, {\"COMPANY_ID\":\"2\",\"COMPANY_DESC\":\"2\",\"COMPANY_CURRENCY\":\"22\",\"ACTIVE\":false,\"IS_HEADOFFICE\":false,\"ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_ID\":\"1\"}]';
    
   var convertToJson = angular.fromJson(myJsonAsText);
   console.log(convertToJson);
   $scope.companies = convertToJson;  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "company in companies track by $index"">
       <p>COMPANY_ID: {{ company.COMPANY_ID }}</p>
       <p>COMPANY_DESC: {{ company.COMPANY_DESC }}</p>
       <p>COMPANY_CURRENCY: {{ company.COMPANY_CURRENCY }}</p>
       <hr>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working. But while I convert to http request it is returning empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the version of Angular. The problem has solved.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js